# app works fine in iphone(all model)s, but crashes only in iPad device and iPad simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

> 2015-05-06 11:36:18.414 Myproject[165:60b] *** -[UIViewAnimationState
>   release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x196b0820

And

> EXC_BREAKPOINT(code=EXC_ARM_BREAKPOINT,subcode=Oxdefe)

This crash does not occur in iPhones (works fine in all iPhone models) and only happens on iPads.

Comment: What you have done for animation? Please add your code..

Comment: Can you put your code here so we can get more idea what happen to it....
I think from your error i guess there is something deallocated and it is called that's why your app is crashing.

Comment: Pleas let me know how I can insert my code with proper format. I am trying to insert my code, but it display in a very bad format. When I insert My code ,it display as simple text file, which will not easy to analysis to you all.

Comment: Please Reply me, I am in trouble. I will thankful to you.

Comment: I fixed some spelling issues.